# OCI - NLB IP Preservation cannot connect to LDAP

Tags: ldap, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to setup a Network Load Balancer with LDAP backends in OCI, but every single `ldapsearch` command times out, e.g: `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<NLB>`.
I can successfully reach the backends directly:
`ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<BACKEND-1>`
This also works if I try to turn off/disable `Preservation Mode`.

The preservation mode keeps the original source IP address and destination IP address:
**Preservation Mode Disabled:**

```
Client > NLB > Backend (request)
Client < NLB < Backend (response)
```

**Preservation Mode Enabled:**

```
Client > NLB > Backend (request)
Client < Backend (response)
```

From the documentation:

> Configure the network load balancer as a route target (private IP next hop following the route rule on the internet gateway (IGW)/dynamic route gateway (DRG) route table). Incoming traffic is not directed to the network load balancer virtual IP but instead is directed to the actual server.

I have a simple architecture, with a single VNC, so I don't really see the need for DRG, since it's all happening inside a single VNC with multiple subnets.

Infrastructure:

```
VNC Network: 192.168.0.0/16


SUBNET A: 192.168.1.0/24  (Client can receive response from backend server directly)
SUBNET B: 192.168.2.0/24  (Client can receive response from backend server directly)
SUBNET C: 192.168.3.0/24  (Subnet for NLB and Backend servers)
```

**Question:** Does this mean I need to update the Route Table for the VNC? Where Target is the NLB IP and destination is the backend servers?